# Railties dependency issues when upgrading to rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.engineyard.com'

gem 'rails',               '~> 3.1.0.rc4'
gem 'sass-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git'
gem 'compass', :git => 'https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git', :branch => 'rails31'
gem 'fancy-buttons'
gem 'haml'
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'https://github.com/AndreasWurm/authlogic.git'#, :branch => 'rails3'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'resque'              
gem 'resque-meta'        
gem 'jquery-rails'     
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'          
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'em-websocket'
gem 'json'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'
```

Whenever I run bundle install, I get the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0.beta)

    rails (~> 3.1.0.rc4) depends on
      railties (3.1.0.rc4)
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove, or comment out, the following:

```
# , :git => 'https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git'
```

Explanation: it has been a while since the last release candidate of Rails 3.1 has been released, a sass-rails gem has been released that works with 3.1 so no need to pull sass-rails from git, and sass-rails master is now looking forward towards Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

try bundle update, that worked for me... Maybe delete all gems, and update rails first, then put gems back and run bundle update again?